# Dynamically populating a div with data from a MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Lets say I have a persons table :

```
forename    surname    age    gender
--------------------------------------------
adam        example    90      male
john        example    90      male
```

If I wanted to display this information in separate divs, how could this be done? Say for example the following HTML.

```
<div class = "container">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class = "jumbotron">
            <!-- adams data here -->
        </div>
        <div class = "jumbotron">
            <!-- johns data here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm aware on how to query the DB to get the information into PHP variables, I'm just not sure how to dynamically display the data in separate divs.

Below is how I am getting the data

```
<?php 

    if($result = $db->query("SELECT forename,surname FROM users ")){
        if($count = $result->num_rows){
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                echo $row->forename, '<br><br>';
                echo $row->surname, '<br><br>';
            }
            $result->free();
       }
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: I've added how I'm getting the variables from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the div inside a loop so you'll print a div for each result row

```
<?php foreach($result as $r): ?>
   <div class = "jumbotron">
     <?php echo $r['name'] // Print fields you need ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT: Now I can see your query. Try this:

```
<?php 
  if($result = $db->query("SELECT forename,surname FROM users ")){
    if($count = $result->num_rows){
      while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
?>
        <div class = "jumbotron">
          <?php echo $row->forename; ?><br><br>
          <?php echo $row->surname; ?><br><br>
        </div>
<?php          
      }
    $result->free();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain $result as $r? I've posted my query above.

Comment: Edited my answer according to new provided info. Check it

Comment: Brilliant! So all I needed so to add the division class in the while loop.

Comment: Yes. Just you must be careful not to mix php and html code and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Well Joe, This is a fairly simple problem that has probably been answered before.
I'll use the `mysqli` class of php

first create a `mysqli` connection object in a file for best practice then include it in your main script.

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli($host_address, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

include this in your main script

```
<?php require "path\to\connection\script"; ?>
<?php
 $sql_adam = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE forename = 'adam'";
 $sql_john = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE forename = 'john'";

 $qry1 = $connection->query($sql_adam);
 $qry2 = $connection->query($sql_john);

?>
<div class = "container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class = "jumbotron">
             <?php if ($qry1->num_rows >= 1){
                while($adam = $qry1->fetch_assoc()){
                    foreach ($adam as $column => $data) {
                       echo  "<p>$column : $data </p>";
                    }
                }
             }
        </div>
        <div class = "jumbotron">
            <?php if ($qry2->num_rows >= 1){
                while($john = $qry2->fetch_assoc()){
                    foreach ($john as $column => $data) {
                       echo  "<p>$column : $data </p>";
                    }
                }
             }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your Result should be something like

```
<div class = "container">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class = "jumbotron">
         <p>forename : adam</p>
         <p>surname : example</p>
         <p>age : 90</p>
         <p>gender : male</p>

      </div>
      <div class = "jumbotron">
         <p>forename : john</p>
         <p>surname : example</p>
         <p>age : 90</p>
         <p>gender : male</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have hardcoded $sql_adam and $sql_john. What if the table has 1000+ names? You have also hardcoded the jumbotron. I was looking for a way to dynamically produce the content.